# Explicitly loading entity's collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, redis

I have this entity  User and it has a roles collection(Set) which I want to redis cache so whenever it's calling getRoles(), it return a cached copy.

Here's the structure so far:

1. User.roles is lazy="true" and access="field".
2. User.getRoles() has a listener that calls a spring @Cacheable method
   which retrieves from redis cache rather than 2nd level cache.

Mapping information:

```
<set
            name="roles"
            table="user_role"
            lazy="true"
            cascade="none"
            access="field"
        >
            <key
                column="user_id"
            >
            </key>
            <many-to-many
                class="com.resolution.scheduler.model.Role"
                column="role_id"
                outer-join="auto"
             />
        </set>
```

Here is GetRoles():

```
public Set getRoles() {
        if(!rolesUpdated  &&  this.id!=null){
            ApplicationContextProviderNonManageBean.getApplicationContext().publishEvent(
                 new com.resolution.scheduler.dao.event.UserRoleGetEvent(this));
        }
                 return roles;
    }
```

Here's what's called when UserRoleGetEvent event fires:

```
@Cacheable(value="userRoleByUserId" , key="#userId", condition="#userId!=null")
    public PersistentSet getUserRoleByUserId(final Long userId){
        if(userId==null){
            return new PersistentSet();
        }
        log.info("USer Role Getting from Database for User Id : "+userId);
        //final List<Role> roles=(List<Role>)getHibernateTemplate().find("Select u.roles from User u  where u.id=?",userId);
        final PersistentSet[] set= new PersistentSet[1];
        getHibernateTemplate().executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback<Object>(){
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException{
                List roles=session.createQuery("Select u.roles from User u  where u.id=:userId").setParameter("userId",userId).list();
                set[0]= new PersistentSet((SessionImpl)session, new HashSet(roles));
                return null;
        }
        });
        log.info(set);

        return set[0];
    }
```

Here's how UserRoleGetEvent works:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(UserRoleGetEvent event) {
        PersistentSet roles = userManager.getUserRoleByUserId(event.getUser().getId());
        event.getUser().setRoles((roles)); //**THIS_SET_MAKES_IT_DIRTY**

    }
```

Problem:
When I do `user.getRole()`, as it set a new collection to user.roles and it makes session dirty. **On this dirty session, whenever flush is called it `delete` all `roles` and it `insert` all roles again even when there was no actual change**. What I'm looking for is how can I make hibernate to think my new collection is like session retrieved(which is not actually) and don't consider it as dirty.

Any workarounds or suggestion?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763402/proper-cache-usage-in-spring-hibernate

Comment: @DraganBozanovic ummm.. No, it's different than what you linked as it's related to loading a child relation.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't like its collections to be changed. What might work is something like:

```
event.getUser().getRoles().clear();
event.getUser().getRoles().addAll(roles);
```

But then, I'm a bit puzzled by what you are trying to do. A `getRoles` on the `User` triggers an event that then changes the roles?

As a side note, I'm working by memory here but your code could be refactored to this:

```
@Cacheable(value="userRoleByUserId" , key="#userId", condition="#userId!=null")
public List<Role> getUserRoleByUserId(final Long userId){
    if(userId==null){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    log.info("USer Role Getting from Database for User Id : "+userId);

    @SuppressWarning("unchecked")
    List<Role> result = (List<Role>) getHibernateTemplate().executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback<Object>(){
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException{
            return session.createQuery("Select u.roles from User u  where u.id=:userId").setParameter("userId",userId).list();
        }
    });
    log.info(set);

    return result;
}

public void onApplicationEvent(UserRoleGetEvent event) {
    List<Role> roles = userManager.getUserRoleByUserId(event.getUser().getId());
    event.getUser().getRoles().clear(); // yes, I know, getRoles will throw an event and send you in an infinite loop...  Fixing that just means having another method
    event.getUser().getRoles().addAll(roles);
}
```

Comment: getRoles() has an event which on trigger, calls getUserRoleByUserId(). Again calling getRoles() will be stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes. That's why I said it will in the line comment. Just use a `getRolesThatDontTriggerAnEvent` method instead